# JHTML date not translating on live server

Tags: joomla2.5

I have some code that displays a date using a custom date format as follows:

```
echo JHtml::_('date',$price->date_from,JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_DM'));
```

Where the string DATE_FORMAT_DM is listed in my spanish language file es-ES.ini as follows:

```
DATE_FORMAT_DM="d M"
```

My problem is that it does not translate the month into Spanish - it works on localhost but not on the live server.

I am completely stumped as to why this is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer, basically there was a problem with the language file loading.
I copied and pasted the date format strings from the main language.ini file into my component ini file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead:

```
echo date($price->date_from, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_DM'));
```

else try using your method but without the language string, therefore this:

```
echo JHtml::_('date',$price->date_from, 'd M');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks lodder, the first throws an error, the second has the same effect as my method- it works on the local server, but not when I upload it to the live server.